# TimeLimiter's callWithTimeout Not working?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

I'm trying to stop/cancel my thread with some timeout with the help of guava library but it not working.

Long callTimeout = 1L;

```
ExecutorService callTimeoutPool= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("name").setDaemon(true).build());
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "[ TimeoutImpl : timedCall ] currentThread name = {0}", new Object[]{Thread.currentThread().getName()});

try
{
     new SimpleTimeLimiter().callWithTimeout(new Callable(){
     @Override
     public Object call()
     {
          int i=0;
          while(true)
          {
               System.out.println(i++);
               if(false)
                    break;
               }
               return true;
               }
           }, callTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
     LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "[ TimeoutImpl : timedCall ]  InterruptedException" ,e );
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     callTimeoutPool.shutdownNow();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "[ TimeoutImpl : timedCall ]  Exception" ,e );
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     callTimeoutPool.shutdownNow();
}
```

I tried Future.cancel also it also not working, please help me on this to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> [Interruption is a cooperative mechanism. When one thread interrupts another, the interrupted thread does not necessarily stop what it is doing immediately.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)

To respond to interrupts, your implementation of `call` must either call a method that responds to interrupts (like `CountDownLatch.await`) or manually check for interrupts through `Thread.interrupted` or `isInterrupted`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, then what can I do for timeout mechanism for one time task (not a while(true);)